# Download files associated with links on a page

Tags: ruby

I have a webpage that has a load of links on it. When clicked, each link allows the user to download a file. I only want the links with a specific term in the href. I don't know how to iterate through all the links and save all the files. I have been using mechanize to generate the code so far

The code is:

```
agent.page.links_with(:href => /DownloadFile/).each do |link|
        #How do I save the file from the link here
end
```

Using updated code

```
agent.page.links_with(:href => /DownloadFile/).each do |link|
    File.open("download.txt", "w") do |f|
        uri = URI(link)
        f << Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    end
end
```

Using updated code again but nothing downloaded

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

agent  = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://mylink")
form = agent.page.forms.first

form.j_username = "usr"
form.j_password = "pwd"
form.submit

#Pick the project you want to download and open it
agent.page.link_with(:text => "AneupGastricCaFSeq").click

agent.page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/).map {|link| 

    link.click

    agent.page.links_with(:href => /DownloadFile/).each do |link|
        link=t+link.uri.to_s
        uri = URI(link)
        File.open("downloaded_file", "w+") do |f|
            f << Net::HTTP.get(uri)
        end
    end
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Net::HTTP` methods to read the file using `GET` request, and save it an file locally.
A sample program is shown below:

```
require 'net/http'

link = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
File.open("download.txt", "w") do |f|
    uri = URI(link)
    f << Net::HTTP.get(uri)
end
```

Comment: OK so to do that over an array of links? Do I do as my updated code suggests?

Comment: Yes, you may want to use different file names for each link instead of `download.txt` which was for illustration purpose.

Comment: OK. Although I have two problems. firstly it is just downloading some html whereas the link is to a file, and secondly the files are getting over written

Comment: Most likely the links that you are discovering through your program are incomplete.

Comment: agreed. Mechanize doesnt give me the full http. Do you know how I can get this. Perhaps by concatenating the first part of the url with http part in it. Can you show me how to do this in the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't much about mechanize.  May be you can update your question and lets see if anyone else can answer it.

Comment: with a switch from `mechanize` to `Net::HTTP` you will loose your session cookies and you can not download the files

Answer (score 1):

you need the agent download the file. because you logged in your website with the agent, then the agent hold your session cookies. if you use then the `Net::HTTP` then you don't have your session cookies.

you need to replace this snippet:

```
    uri = URI(link)
    File.open("downloaded_file", "w+") do |f|
        f << Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    end
```

with this:

```
    agent.get(uri).save!('downloaded_file')
```

and you need to add a pluggable_parser to direct save the file without to hold it memory:

```
    agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
```

the full code is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

dir = 'your/path/to/save'

agent  = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download

agent.get("http://mylink")
form = agent.page.forms.first

form.j_username = "usr"
form.j_password = "pwd"
form.submit

#Pick the project you want to download and open it
agent.page.link_with(:text => "AneupGastricCaFSeq").click

agent.page.links_with(:href => /ViewSample/).map {|link| 

    link.click

    agent.page.links_with(:href => /DownloadFile/).each do |link|
        link=t+link.uri.to_s
        uri = URI(link)

        #your custom function to generate a distinct filename
        filename = filename_from_link(link)          
        agent.get(uri).save!(File.join(dir, filename))
    end
}
```